# Is there any way to get repeat page headers in crystal report export excel format?

Tags: c#, excel, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report to export formats like pdf, csv and excel for student records. When I am trying to export to excel the page header (eg. title, page no, footer) are not repeating for each student in excel , it is working fine in pdf and csv files.

Any solution to repeat page header,page no,footer for each student record using c# asp.net crystal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export a crystal report to Excel you should get a pop-up that looks like this.

[image]

In the middle of this window is an option for "Export page headers and page footers:" and you should be able to control this setting as desired using the drop-down box.  Just set it to "On each page" and you should be good to go.

One thing to note, if you are exporting to Excel as "Data-only" the pop-up window for Excel Format Options will be different and will not include the same controls for this feature.  When exporting as Data-only there will just be a check box for "Export page header and page footer", and this will only export the page header and footer once for the entire report.

Edit:  Here is a link that might help with the API for Excel Format Options on an exported report.  [Click here to see an example with code.](https://answers.sap.com/questions/9726899/excel-formatting-issues-when-using-crystal-reports.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply..can I get without this popup? And need clarification is crystal report support repeat headers and footers in Excel with report settings?

Comment: @BusireddyNavya I have edited my answer to include a link to a question on the SAP forums that might be useful.  It has an example with code of how someone else approached this type of export.

Comment: I tried the code it works fine but I need a page break for every record, for each record I am getting new page but the footer is coming in next page of each record I need this to be in continue with each record? any suggestions please post

Comment: There are a few things that can cause this to happen.  Most commonly its the total height of the sections that appear on a single page exceed the height of the page settings in page setup.  If you have blank space in your details sections or in the footer section that is pushing onto the next page you could try removing as much as possible to reduce the height of those sections.  You can also edit Page Setup and reduce the top and bottom margins to allow for more vertical space on the page before a section is pushed to a new page.  If that doesn't work, I would open a new question for this.